# CNAME for AWS Load Balancer and Certificate

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, aws-application-load-balancer, aws-certificate-manager

I certified my domain using AWS Certificate Mangager which requires to add a CNAME to my current domain. So far so good, verfication worked.

Now I set up a load balancer. As the public IP can change over time, it's not advised to set an A record to my domain. AWS tells me to add another CNAME record that points to the endpoint of my load balancer. This is not possible as I am not able to set two CNAME records.

Does anyone know a workaround?

Answer (score 0):

Ok it's late. I AM able to set two CNAME records. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: On AWS, you can also use an [_alias record_](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/resource-record-sets-choosing-alias-non-alias.html) which is a kind of A record that points to your load balancer dynamically. These offer some more flexibility compared to CNAMEs.